# Issue in sending mails in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to php.I had created a sample table to send the data through mail but when i click on the button it is redirecting to default page and when I refresh the page I am getting the mails without clicking on the button.Please Help me and solve my issue.

Here is my code:

```
 <div>
    <b> Hello <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>!</b><br>
    <b>Email    :</b> <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>.<br>
    <b>Gender   :</b> <?php echo $_POST["gender"]; ?>.<br>
 <b>Birthday    :</b>
  <?php
     $day = $_POST['day'];
     $month = $_POST['month'];
     $year = $_POST['year'];
     $date = $day."-".$month."-".$year;
     $my_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
     echo $my_date;
    ?>
</div>

<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="vaccination-form">
  <div>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">

  <tr>
   <th id= "sno" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;" class="bg-color" width="5%">S.No</th>
   <th id= "vaccine" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;" class="bg-color center" width="32%">Vaccine</th>      
   <th id="decsription" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;">Description</th>
<th id="duedate" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;" class ="bg-color" width="15%">Due Date</th>

 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><a href="http://www.labwise.in/devel/hepatitis-b/" style="color: rgb(0,255,0)"><font color="#0000FF">Hepatitis B</font></a>
</td>       
<td>

        <b><span> At birth: </span></b><br></br>
        <span>For infants born to hepatitis B surface antigen (HBsAg)-positive mothers, administer HepB vaccine and 0.5 mL of hepatitis B immune globulin (HBIG) within 12 hours of birth. These infants should be tested for HBsAg and antibody to HBsAg (anti-HBs) 1 to 2 months after completion of the HepB series at age 9 through 18 months (preferably at the next well-child visit).</span>

     <div>
  <?php

      $date=date_create("now");
      $bdate=date_create($my_date);

      //echo date_format($dueDate,'d-m-Y');

        if($date >= $bdate)
        {
            $dueDate=$bdate->modify('+6 week');
            echo date_format($dueDate,"d-m-Y");
        }
        else
        {
            $bdate->modify('+2 week');
            echo date_format($bdate,'d-m-Y');
        }
   ?>

</div>


</td>
</tr> 
</table>



<div>
      <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Me') ?>" value="submit "class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Email Me')?></span></span></button>

</div> 
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('vaccination-form', true);
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "sendmail.php", 
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
  }
});
</script>
```

sendmail.php

```
<?php

        if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
        { 
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $to=$email;
            $subject= "New Application";
            $message= "Name: ".$name;
            $headers= "From: admin@labwise.in" . "\r\n" ;
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }

?>
```

Comment: From where you are trying to send mail? from your local or live server??

Comment: The logic of your script is: create a form, send an email. But it should be: create a form but if there is a post request with valid input send a mail instead. You need to wrap your code with an `if else` condition

Comment: Open it up Firefox, open firebug and see what's happening with the ajax request first - what is the response? Do you even know that the ajax request is successful?

Comment: Can we add the variables in subject in mail() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I added all the files regarding your need.

Your First file

```
    <div>
        <b> Hello <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>!</b><br>
        <b>Email    :</b> <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>.<br>
        <b>Gender   :</b> <?php echo $_POST["gender"]; ?>.<br>
     <b>Birthday    :</b>
      <?php
         $day = $_POST['day'];
         $month = $_POST['month'];
         $year = $_POST['year'];
         $date = $day."-".$month."-".$year;
         $my_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
         echo $my_date;
        ?>
    </div>
    <form action="sendmail.php" method="post" id="vaccination-form">
        <div>
            <table border="1" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th id= "sno" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;" class="bg-color" width="5%">S.No</th>
                    <th id= "vaccine" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;" class="bg-color center" width="32%">Vaccine</th>      
                    <th id="decsription" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;">Description</th>
                    <th id="duedate" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;" class ="bg-color" width="15%">Due Date</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.labwise.in/devel/hepatitis-b/" style="color: rgb(0,255,0)"><font color="#0000FF">Hepatitis B</font></a></td>       
                    <td><b><span> At birth: </span></b><br></br>
                    <span>For infants born to hepatitis B surface antigen (HBsAg)-positive mothers, administer HepB vaccine and 0.5 mL of hepatitis B immune globulin (HBIG) within 12 hours of birth. These infants should be tested for HBsAg and antibody to HBsAg (anti-HBs) 1 to 2 months after completion of the HepB series at age 9 through 18 months (preferably at the next well-child visit).</span></td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
            <div>
                    <input type="hidden"  name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden"  name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden"  name="dueDate" value="<?php echo date_format($bdate,'d-m-Y'); ?>">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Me') ?>" value="submit "class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Email Me')?></span></span></button>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('vaccination-form', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Now your `sendmail.php`

```
<?php
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $dudate=$_POST['dueDate'];//do what you want to do with due date
        $to=$email;
        $subject= "New Application";
        $message= "Name: ".$name;
        $headers= "From: admin@labwise.in" . "\r\n" ;
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo 'sucess';
?>
```

Just replace the two codes in files.

Try this and let me know what is happening..

**CHECK THIS mail() FUNCTION**

```
$to         = '===YOUR to Address==';
$uid        = md5(uniqid(time()));
$header     = "From: ".'==NAME=='." <".'==EMAIL ADDRESS=='.">\r\n";
$header    .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header    .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header    .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header    .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header    .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header    .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header    .= "Hi    \r\n\r\n";
$header    .= "=====MESSAGE 1===== \n\n";
$header    .= "=====MESSAGE 2=====  \r\n\r\n";
$sub        = "====SUBJECT OF MAIL====";
mail($to, $sub, "" , $header);
```

In this method you can add more messages in email.. Its simple too..

Comment: When I refresh the page the mails are receiving but not getting when I click on the "email me " button.

Comment: Yes the server is enabled with sending mail

Comment: Have you checked the variables that you are included, that contain the email id and all?? am asking because am getting every mail..when I given static mail ids directly.

Comment: Yes,I have checked all the variables but when I click on the button am not getting any mail.

Comment: No,It is getting same issue.It is redirecting to default page after click on the button.

Comment: Should I write a mail function in another file.

Comment: yes.. what I said Write the mail function in another file and pass the variables to that file.. You can use help of `ajax` functionality if needed.

Comment: Please check my code now I added with ajax and in sendmail.php I added the mail function.But,the button doesn't works.

Comment: add this action in your form ie, `<form action="sendmail.php" method="post" id="vaccination-form">`

Comment: It is going to new page with the url http://www.labwise.in/devel/vaccination-details/sendmail.php

Comment: But the mails are not receiving when i write a print statement it is printing on the new page.

Comment: have you checked by giving static email and message in that mail function and check.

Comment: sorry by using static email and message in mail function I can send a mail

Comment: Yes,I got the mail it is worked.But how to do it as a dynamic by getting name and email variables

Comment: OK.. that means you are not getting the variables properly.. the values in varibles..make it corect and try.. :)

Comment: Thanq.can you please suggest me how to get those variables.

Comment: Already I have created a name variable in the form.From that how can I get the name variable in sendmail.php file.

Comment: give me ur mail id. i'll mail the file

Comment: I am waiting for your mail.Please send the file.

Comment: Where is the ajax function in the form.

Comment: in this case no ajax is needed...its form submission.. If you are using ajax in your manner..it will trigger when the page loads..otherwise it should add on the button click using javascript.

Comment: Yes,I got the mail with the name.In the same way how can I get the "vaccine" and due date variables.I had tried but it has not worked

Comment: add hidden variables like that i given .. it will get in sendmail.php as $_POST..

Comment: In the same way I tried i can get only vaccine but not due date.

Comment: just now I added the due date code in the table once check it and suggest me please.

Comment: Ok.How to add more variables in message i want to add vaccine variable in message.

Comment: Check the new mail()  i added.. in that method u can add more variables in email

Comment: ok thanq can I use else statement for mail() function with the message "mail is not sent succesfully"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $to=$email;
        $subject= "New Application";
        $message= "Name: ".$name;
        $headers= "From: admin@labwise.in" . "\r\n" .
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        unset($_POST["submit"]);
    }
        ?>
```

Put condition to check where submit button is clicked to not and then unset it for future use

Comment: I tried with your code but it is going to default page when I click on the button and I am not getting any mail

Comment: First in if condition check whether that block is getting executed or not i.e do  echo 'in if block'; and if it is going in if block then echo mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); then check what it is returning